# Curve not smooth after deleting more than n-3 vertices, where n is amount of every vertex in path

Tags: bezier-curves

After when I add a path, enter edit mode, and delete every vertex, except for 3 vertices, then the path is smooth:
[image]

But when I delete every vertex, except for 2 or 1 vertices, and extrude vertex 3, then the path is not smooth anymore. How can I fix this?
[image]

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you delete a vertex the path order gets lower ( can't have order greater than number of vertices and the max is 6 )
so just change the spline order back to 3 or higher and it will be smooth again :

[image]